# Sync data from Amazon Aurora to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis, amazon-aurora, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to setup a sync between AWS Aurora and Redshift. What is the best way to achieve this sync?

Possible ways to sync can be: -

1. Query table to find changes in a table(since I am only doing inserts, updates don't matter), export these changes to a flat file in S3 bucket and use Redshift copy command to insert into Redshift.
2. Use [python publisher](https://github.com/noplay/python-mysql-replication) and Boto3 to publish changes into a Kinesis stream and then consume this stream in Firehose from where I can copy directly into Redshift.
3. Use Kinesis Agent to detect changes in binlog (Is it possible to detect changes int binlog using Kinesis Agent) and publish it to Firehose and from there copy into Firehose.

I haven't explored AWS Datapipeline yet.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/dms/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As pointed out by @Mark B, the [AWS Database Migration Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html) can migrate data between databases. This can be done as a one-off exercise, or it can run continuously, keeping two databases in sync.

The documentation shows that [Amazon Aurora can be a source](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.MySQL.html) and [Amazon Redshift can be a target](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Target.Redshift.html).

Comment: Amazon Aurora can be a source *only* if it's mySQL compatible. Aurora Postgres and Redshift would the ideal match

Answer (score 1):

AWS has just announced this new feature: [Amazon Aurora zero-ETL integration with Amazon Redshift](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/11/amazon-aurora-zero-etl-integration-redshift/)

This natively provides near real-time (second) synchronization from Aurora to Redshift.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use federated queries: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/federated-overview.html