# Merge data from multiple tables in RDS to export to Redshift using AWS DMS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I am setting up a continuous replication from RDS to Redshift using **AWS DMS**, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44598515/sync-data-from-amazon-aurora-to-redshift). My usecase requires me to combine data from multiple RDS tables to export to Redshift. For eg. RDS has Tables School, Student, District. I want to export data like:-

```
select sch.Name, stu.Name, dis.Name from School sch inner join Student stu on stu.schoolid = sch.id inner join District dis on dis.id = sch.districtid;
```

So, I want to select columns from multiple tables and export to a single Redshift table. Is selection from multiple tables possible using AWS DMS?

Comment: what type of database is your RDS?